# Label is not using custom font

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, fonts

I'm loading an embedded font using this code:

```
PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection(); //declared outside this function

using (Stream fontStream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("NucWar.BSOD_Font.ttf"))
{
    if (null == fontStream)
    {
        return;
    }

    int fontStreamLength = (int)fontStream.Length;

    IntPtr data = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(fontStreamLength);

    byte[] fontData = new byte[fontStreamLength];
    fontStream.Read(fontData, 0, fontStreamLength);

    Marshal.Copy(fontData, 0, data, fontStreamLength);

    pfc.AddMemoryFont(data, fontStreamLength);

    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(data);
}
```

And that works fine. If I throw a breakpoint down at the end I can see the font is successfully loaded. If I wire-up the `Paint` event, and use this:

```
bool bold = false;
bool italic = false;

e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Point;

using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
{
    int y = 5;

    foreach (FontFamily fontFamily in pfc.Families)
    {
        if (fontFamily.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Regular))
        {
            using (Font font = new Font(fontFamily, 32, FontStyle.Regular))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(font.Name, font, b, 5, y, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
            }
            y += 40;
        }
        if (fontFamily.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Bold))
        {
            bold = true;
            using (Font font = new Font(fontFamily, 32, FontStyle.Bold))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(font.Name, font, b, 5, y, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
            }
            y += 40;
        }
        if (fontFamily.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Italic))
        {
            italic = true;
            using (Font font = new Font(fontFamily, 32, FontStyle.Italic))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(font.Name, font, b, 5, y, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
            }
            y += 40;
        }

        if (bold && italic)
        {
            using (Font font = new Font(fontFamily, 32, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(font.Name, font, b, 5, y, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
            }
            y += 40;
        }

        using (Font font = new Font(fontFamily, 32, FontStyle.Underline))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(font.Name, font, b, 5, y, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
            y += 40;
        }

        using (Font font = new Font(fontFamily, 32, FontStyle.Strikeout))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(font.Name, font, b, 5, y, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
        }
    }
}
```

that too works fine, the font is painted on the form 5 times as it should.

So I find it very confusing when I use this function:

```
//Yes, pts is a valid size. eg 16, 20, 22, 30
private void AdjustFontSize(float pts)
{
    int count = 0;
    //_yPos is a dict<string, int> that contains the Name of each Label control, and its original Y position
    // Therefore, Keys contains the Name prop of each label
    foreach (var lbl in _yPos.Keys)                                 
    {
        var con = Controls[lbl] as Label; //Current label
        FontFamily f = pfc.Families[0]; //Get the font out of pfc. Debugging confirms that f is not null and has a font in it.

        //Why this no work? It works fine if I use a built in font, like "Times"
        con.Font = new Font(f, pts, FontStyle.Regular); 

        //Messing with the location prop, still working on it. Probably not important
        con.Location = new Point(con.Location.X, (int) (_yPos[lbl] + Math.Pow(1.15, (int) pts)*count++)); 

    }
}
```

And the label font changes to Arial, not me desired font. What is really bothering me is that If I change `con.Font = ...` to use `"Times"` instead of `f` It correctly changes to the Times font. And on top of that, I know the font is loaded properly because the form paints correctly. By that logic, I am changing the font properly, and I'm loading the font properly, so it should work.

Comment: sounds strange, is there something special with the font you loaded? I mean you can try another font file and see if it works, there may be some difference between the default text rendering of a control with the custom drawing with GDI+.

Comment: as far as I can tell, its just a normal TTF. Ill give another file a go and see what happens.

Comment: Your AdjustFontSize method is setting the Font for all your labels by creating new fonts, but when the labels are redrawn, your paint logic uses the original fonts that you loaded.

Comment: The paint event was just to test if the font worked. It is not actually running with the labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set [`UseCompatibleTextRendering`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.usecompatibletextrendering%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to true to use a locally loaded font that isn't a part of the windows font library.

A `Label` has 2 rendering paths the first (and default) is to use GDI rendering which can't use the `Font` object and needs to convert it to an internal format and expects the actual font to be in the windows library.

The second path used when `UseCompatibleTextRendering` is true is to use GDI+ and looks a lot like your paint method by using the `Graphics.DrawString` method and passing in the `Font` assigned to the label.

You can also set the setting globally rather than on each control by using the [`Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setcompatibletextrenderingdefault%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which would already exist in your Program.cs that is created by default with a WinForms application.

Comment: I didn't realize it would be that simple. Thanks! Here's your 50 rep as promised.